# How to change style-properties of one element when another element is hovered purely in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I know how to change style of an element on hover but i want to change style of another element when first element is focused or hovered.

Comment: it all depends on your hierarchy. Please include some of your markup and narrow down the issue for us to better help you. Also review this for good measure: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: The adjacent selectors might be of use here, if the elements are next to each other. Documentation on these: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator

Comment: my question was a bit different and however I got the answer :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is purely dependent on your HTML structure.

If your affected element is a child of the trigger element, then you can use the pattern

```css
.[TRIGGER_PARENT_CLASS]:hover .[AFFECTED_CHILD_CLASS]
```

This pattern can nest as deep as you would like. It is also worth noting that you may want to use the [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to select a direct child element.

If your affected element is a sibling of your trigger element, and the trigger element is directly preceding the affected element you can use pattern:

```css
.[TRIGGER_CLASS]:hover ~ .[AFFECTED_SIBLING_CLASS]
```

You can learn more about [Child and Sibling Selectors in this CSS-Tricks article](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)